# JSON.net access nested arrays, objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

how can I access in this JSON (http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations.json?includeTimeseries=true&includeCurrentMeasurement=true) the nested array like
timeseries.shortname? I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
string url = "http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations.json?includeTimeseries=true&includeCurrentMeasurement=true";

HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream));
    dynamic info = JArray.Load(reader);

    foreach (var item in info)
    {
        myModel.Add(new ItemModel()
        {
            uuid = item.uuid,
            number = item.number,
            city_longname = item.longname,
            timeseries = item.timeseries.shortname
        });
    }
}
```

The 3 items works, but the last (timeseries) gives the following error: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: What is the *actual* JSON response? I would suspect it is missing or is being accessed incorrectly. Make sure to include the relevant data in questions (and don't expect people to follow links :).

Comment: the VS debugger only gives the "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" response

Comment: `timeseries` is an array, try `item.timeseries[0].shortname`

Answer (score 0):

The `dynamic` properties give you `JToken` objects. Using the `Value` property on those gives you the `string` representation. In order to get it type-safe you need to parse/convert. Since you did not provide your `ItemModel` class details I cannot help you here.

```
myModel.Add(new ItemModel()
{
  uuid = item.uuid.Value,
  number = item.number.Value,
  city_longname = item.longname.Value
});
```

The `timeseries` property is a `JArray` object. You cannot get to the `shortname` property directly. You have to choose an index first (`item.timeseries[5]`, for instance, give you the `JObject` instance you are after). The details regarding getting the actual values in a type-safe manner from above apply here as well.